# Comparing dates of different formats and matching it from another file

Tags: shell-script, shell, date

I have two data files with date stamps in different formats
(as text in the file contents). 
I wish to compare the two dates and print the variable from one file to another according to date in a shell script. 
I have a script in MATLAB, but I’d like to do it in a shell script. 
In one file, the date format is `2017-01-01 12:00:00`.
In the other file it is `20170101 1200`.
For a variable I want to compare it with date in `file1`
and if it matches print variable as column in `file1` from `file2`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, please take [the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to see how to ask good questions. As a rule you need to include samples of your input files, the code you have tried, the output you got and the output you want. If you update your question with these then people will be able to give better help so ... please add this detail.

Comment: Read `man date`, and use the `--date=` and `--format=` options to convert both dates to "seconds since the epoch".

Comment: @waltinator, what version of date has a --format option?

Comment: As bu5hman says: (1) Show samples of your input *files.* Is `file1` 20 characters long (e.g., `2017-01-01 12:00:00` and a newline, and nothing else)? Is `file2` 14 characters long (e.g., `20170101 1200` and a newline, and nothing else)? If not, you haven't shown us samples of your input files.  (2) Show what output you want/expect.  (3) Show us your MATLAB script. (P.S. Does it work the way you want?)  (4) Try to do this in a shell script, and show us your best attempt. … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain bash with parameter substitution:

```bsh
dateA='2017-01-01 12:00:00'
dateB='20170101 1200'

tmpA=${dateA//[-:]/}   # remove hyphens and colons
# next expansion excludes last 2 characters
[[ "${tmpA:0:-2}" == "$dateB" ]] && echo same || echo different
```

```
same
```

Older bash versions don't support negative lengths, but you can use `${tmpA:0:${#tmpA}-2}`